# Using jQuery and CSS3's TranslateX() to reveal an element while scrolling parent element into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, transform

I would like to change the position of a circle when it's parent section is scrolled into view.

While scrolling down after the parent is in view, it should move to the right and when scrolling up, it should move back to where it was originally. (-200px to the left) It should only be moved while the user is actively scrolling.

If the user scrolls all the way down to the very bottom of the circle's parent section, or if they have already scrolled down to the bottom and reload the page, the circle should appear in it's fully-revealed position.

My current code partially works, but I'm having trouble with getting the entire element to appear based on how much of the parent element is visible and also getting it to display in it's final position when reloading the page after having scrolled to the very bottom.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/gu2rvnsw/

```js
var $window = $(window),
    $sectionFour = $('.section-four'),
    $circle = $sectionFour.find('.circle'),
    lastScrollTop = 0,
    position = -200;

function revealCircle() {
  var isVisible,
   st = $window.scrollTop();

  isVisible = isInView($sectionFour);

  if (isVisible) {
    // console.log('section four is in view, so lets do stuff!');

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
      if (position === 0) {
        return false
      }
      $circle.css('transform', 'translateX(' + position + 'px')
      position++;
    } else {
      if (position === -200) {
        return false
      }
      $circle.css('transform', 'translateX(' + position + 'px')
      position--;
    }
  }
}

function isInView(node) {
  var rect;

  if (typeof jQuery === 'function' && node instanceof jQuery) {
    node = node[0];
  }

  rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
    (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0) &&
    rect.bottom >= 0 &&
    rect.right >= 0 &&
    rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}

$window.on('scroll', revealCircle);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-200px); }

.section {
  min-height: 400px; }
  .section-one {
    background-color: red; }
  .section-two {
    background-color: orange; }
  .section-three {
    background-color: yellow; }
  .section-four {
    background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section section-one"></section>
<section class="section section-two"></section>
<section class="section section-three"></section>
<section class="section section-four">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified a bit. The only value you need to keep track of as the page is scrolled is `scrollTop()`. Because the geometry of `$sectionFour` never changes, you can cache its `getBoundingClientRect()` right away.

Once you know that `$sectionFour` is in view, you want to figure out how many pixels of its total height are in view, convert that to a percentage, and then apply that percentage to the initial position of -200. Essentially, when only a few pixels are showing, that's a small percentage, such as 10% and -200 becomes -180. When the element is fully in view, the percentage should be near 100%, and -200 becomes 0. This means you're not keeping track of the last position or which direction the scroll was, you're just computing what the value should be based on the current viewport (scrollTop).

```js
var $window = $(window),
  $sectionFour = $('.section-four'),
  $circle = $sectionFour.find('.circle');
  rect = $sectionFour[0].getBoundingClientRect();

function revealCircle() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $window[0].innerHeight;

  if (scrollTop + windowHeight > rect.top) {    
    var percentVisible = (scrollTop - (rect.top - windowHeight)) / rect.height;
    var position = 200 - (percentVisible * 200);
    
    $circle.css('transform', 'translateX(-' + position + 'px');
  }
}

$window.on('scroll', revealCircle);
```

```css
body { margin:0;}

.circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
  -moz-border-radius: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateX(-200px); }

.section {
  min-height: 400px; }
  .section-one {
    background-color: red; }
  .section-two {
    background-color: orange; }
  .section-three {
    background-color: yellow; }
  .section-four {
    background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section section-one"></section>
<section class="section section-two"></section>
<section class="section section-three"></section>
<section class="section section-four">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This looks good, however, after scrolling to the bottom of the page, then reloading the page, the circle appears -200px offscreen instead of at 0. Any ideas how to fix? I tried adding "load" to the window on() event listener but it didn't help.

Comment: You probably don't have all of the variables cached in the load event. Just call `revealCircle()` directly as the last line of your JS.

Answer (score 0):

It could be more simpler to use css variables for pure JS solution :

```js
const sectFour  = document.querySelector('#section-four')
    , divCircle = sectFour.querySelector('.circle')


function percentVisible(elm)
  {
  let rect       = elm.getBoundingClientRect()
    , viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight)
    , visu       = viewHeight-rect.top

  return (visu<0) ? -1 : Math.min( 100, (visu/rect.height*100))
  // return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0)  =>  checkVisible
  }

window.onscroll=_=>
  {
  let circlePos = percentVisible(sectFour) *2

  if (circlePos>=0)
    {
    divCircle.style.setProperty('--circle-pos', `-${200-circlePos}px`)
    // IE 11 : // divCircle.style=('transform:translateX(-'+(200-circlePos)+'px')
    }
  }
```

```css
* { margin: 0 }

.circle {
  --circle-pos         :-200px;
  width                : 400px;
  height               : 400px;
  background-color     : #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
     -moz-border-radius: 200px;
          border-radius: 200px;
  transform            : translateX(var(--circle-pos));
  /* IE 11 ........... : translateX(-200px); */
}

section { min-height: 400px;  }
section:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: red;    }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: orange; }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: yellow; }
section:nth-of-type(4) { background-color: green;  }
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section id="section-four"> <div class="circle"></div> </section>
```

Comment: That's a great solution, however, I need it to work in IE 11. Do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Cofey   : without css variables you can use : `divCircle.style=('transform:translateX(-'+(200-circlePos)+'px')`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), this was designed to solve problems like yours. Listening to scroll event and calculating the position can result in bad performance.

First, you have to define the options for the IO:

```
let options = {
  root: document.querySelectorAll('.section-four'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

After defining the options you have to tell the observer which elements to observe, I guess in your case this would be `.section-four`:

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.section-four');
targets.forEach(target => {
  observer.observe(target) } 
)
```

Final step is to define the callback function that should be executed once `.section-four` is getting into view:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element
    // here you can do something like $(entry.target).find('circle') to get your circle
  });
};
```

Have a look at [this demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Result), depending on how much the element is visible the background-color changes. I think this comes close to your problem, you just don't change the bg-color you animate the circle inside the element.

There is also another demo on the site that displays how much of an element is visible on the screen, maybe this suits you better.

You can also use this [polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers.